# stopping weblogic server 8.1 from console

Tags: weblogic8.x

I am using weblogic server 8.1 with MyEclipse and started the command propmt with "startweblogic" command.

I can't post image due to less reputation so I'm just writing the command like I wrote on my console:

E:\JLC\bea8\user_projects\domains\MyDomain>startweblogic

and my server is started after this.

now instead of just closing the window, I want to stop the server properly, but I don't know how to do it. It seems that I can't type anything in the console. So please someone tell me how to stop the server properly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe pressing Ctrl+C in the console...but closing windows console is well too.
If you want to keep opened your cmd, first open a new cmd, navigate to the weblogic bat file, start server and then press Ctrl+C to stop server. Doing that, you could start server again pressing key up and enter. 
(sorry for my bad english)